# Best way to add a WordPress plugin's options to a non-admin user's menu

Tags: wordpress

I often configure WordPress installations for less-technical people and find that the first important task is to remove unnecessary items from the admin panel, however this becomes increasingly-difficult to manage when plugins get enabled and the "locked-down" users need access to its functions.

Generally, I create a new Role from scratch (using members plugin) and disable things from there.

The problem is that to allow a locked-down user to access the settings for a plugin (to *add* an item to their admin menu) I generally have to find the `add_menu_page` function and change the capability to one I know the locked-down user will have which, while good for allowing users access based on capabilities, makes little sense when I just want to allow the Role access to the menu.

More importantly, however, I dislike having to edit a plugin's code; particularly as it requires readjusting with each plugin update. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this or am I just approaching this issue in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by identifying which capability the plugin required and adding it to the role.